# How to make an irregular shape component clickable? Android

Tags: android, button

I want to make a clickable component with this irregular shape, but I have no idea how I could do it, I have been looking for a couple of days but I have not seen any solution. There should be text and images inside the component.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Use a MaterialButton with a custom ShapeAppareance

Comment: @gabrielemariotti I'm looking for but can't see the shapeappareance property for MaterialButton

Comment: Check the [CornerTreatments and EdgeTreatment](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#materialshapedrawable-and-shapeappearancemodel)

Comment: @gabrielemariotti yes, but is for rounded corners or cut corners, i need an "inverse rounded" corners. Or something I'm not seeing ... Can you clarify it me?

Comment: You can build your own CornerTreatment. Just "draw" the corner path. In my answer you can find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Material Components Library you can define [`CornerTreatment`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#materialshapedrawable-and-shapeappearancemodel) to apply to the components.
There are some built-in `CornerTreatment` like [`CutCornerTreatment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/CutCornerTreatment) or [`RoundedCornerTreatment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/RoundedCornerTreatment) but you can built your own CornerTreatment.

Something like:

```
class ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment : CornerTreatment() {

  override fun getCornerPath(
      shapePath: ShapePath,
      angle: Float,
      interpolation: Float,
      radius: Float
  ) {
    val interpolatedRadius = radius * interpolation
    shapePath.reset(0f, interpolatedRadius, ANGLE_LEFT, ANGLE_LEFT - angle)
    shapePath.addArc(
        -interpolatedRadius,
        -interpolatedRadius,
        interpolatedRadius,
        interpolatedRadius,
        ANGLE_BOTTOM,
        -angle
    )
  }

  companion object {
    const val ANGLE_LEFT = 180f
    const val ANGLE_BOTTOM = 90f
  }
}
```

And just apply it to the Button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/concave"
    app:cornerRadius="16dp"
    ..>
```

with:

```
    val materialButton = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id....)
    val concaveRoundedCornerTreatment = ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment()

    materialButton.shapeAppearanceModel = materialButton.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
            .setTopRightCorner(concaveRoundedCornerTreatment)
            .build()
```

[image]

Comment: @JoSeBu Yes, you can apply the `CornerTreatment` also in a `MaterialCardView`. In general you can apply it to all views with a `MaterialShapeDrawable`.

Comment: I am testing changing only: val materialButton = findViewById<MaterialCardView>(R.id.concave) but When I compile the field does not appear, do I have to change something else?

Comment: @JoSeBu Just use the `id` in your layout.

Comment: yes, but when I compile the code the component does not appear in the view

Comment: @JoSeBu which version of material components are you using and without applying the CornerTreatment does the components appear?

Comment: i think that the version is this: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' and yes, without applying CornerTreatment the component appear

Comment: I am using the 1.2.0-beta01, but to be honest I am not sure that the issue is the version. There is nothing special in my layout.

Comment: because indeed the version was the problem, with your version it works correctly, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

create a shape drawable like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <stroke
            android:width=".05dp"
            android:color="#d2d2d2" />
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="410dp"
    android:left="100dp"
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:top="-300dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

then set this drawable as background for your view(eg:linearlayout)
Note:please adjust the dimensions according to your need

Comment: ok, this is to put it vertical, I have tried with rotate and I could not rotate it, only one square comes out.
And with this I would have the problem that I cannot put any type of shadow, in the end this is like putting a background image. From what I see making forms of this style it is not contemplated in android, right?