# is there a way to make an inward radius to a button in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm trying to make a button that his corner should be cut inwards and close to an floating button.
i know i can do a round corner with the `<shape/>` and `<corners/>` in drawable but i want the corner "to eat up" the button.
is that even possible?

like in this picture:
[image: the button near the floating button]

Comment: use ImageButton and place image like this on it. without any text.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237512/how-to-make-an-irregular-shape-component-clickable-android/62243826#62243826